# script to check when a directory is last updated

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am trying to write a script that takes the last update date of a hadoop path subtracts it from  current date and sends out an email if the difference is more than a certain number of days (variable).It  needs to loop through a pipe delimited config file which has the number of days, table name,hadoop path and email

example of config file

```
30|db.big_leasing_center|/TST/DL/EDGE_BASE/GFDCP-52478/BIG_LEASING_CENTER/Data/|abcd@gmail.com

2|db.event|/TST/DL/EDGE_BASE/GFDCP-52478/GFDCP01P-ITG_FIN_DB/EVENTS/Data/|cab@gmail.com
```

below is what i tried

```
#!/bin/ksh

check_last_refresh() {



                DAYS=$1
                TABLE=$2
                HDP_PATH=$3
                EMAIL_DL=$4
                last_refresh_date=$(hdfs dfs -ls $HDP_PATH | grep '^-' | awk '{print $6}' | sort -rh | head -1)

                echo $last_refresh_date

          diff=$(( ( $(date '+%s') - $(date '+%s' -d "$last_refresh_date") ) / 86400 ))

           echo $diff

              if [ "$diff" -gt "$DAYS" ]; then

             echo "HI for $TABLE has an issue" | mail -s "HI for $TABLE has an issue, Please check" -b  $EMAIL_DL

            fi
     return 0

}


cat /data/scratchSpace/bznhd9/CONFIG.txt | while read line; do
                DAYS=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $1}')
                TABLE=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $2}')
                HDP_PATH=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $3}')
                EMAIL_DL=$(echo $line|awk -F'|' '{print $4}')

          echo $TABLE
                r=$(check_last_refresh $DAYS $TABLE $HDP_PATH $EMAIL_DL)
        echo $r
done
```

Please help

Comment: Why did you tag this bash if you're using ksh?

Comment: With spaces before the SHEBANG the SHEBANG is ignored.

Comment: Offtopic: `while IFS="|" read -r days table hdb_path email_dl other_fields; do ... done <  CONFIG.txt` avoids `awk`.